# Force Amazon S3 JPG Download - Attachment Headers URL

Tags: php, amazon-s3, http-headers

I'm simply (or not) trying to force a JPG download from my Amazon bucket, like this:

```
function get_s3_signed_url($bucket, $resource, $AWS_S3_KEY, $AWS_s3_secret_key, $expire_seconds) {
    $expires = time()+$expire_seconds;

    $string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n{$expires}\n/".str_replace(".s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com","", $bucket)."/$resource";
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode((hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), $AWS_s3_secret_key, TRUE))));

    $authentication_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWS_S3_KEY;
    $authentication_params.= "&Expires={$expires}";
    $authentication_params.= "&Signature={$signature}";

    return $link = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonAWS.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";
}

$url = get_s3_signed_url( $aws_bucketName, 'website-hires-photos/photo/'.$filename, $aws_access_key_id, $aws_s3_secret, 30);

header('Content-Type: images/jpg');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$url."\""); 
readfile($url);
```

But I'm getting a load of jargon, like this:

> zóPcg”`îZ~ØsÍêïJ#£Aq$ÓÒ†Nkèk�Á+bÊ˛«∏k.≠ªÄ‡K©˜‰˚FπæÜ`v§›†˘π#kGGº~{ÖlüûËˇ�¢¨Ü±S_πÌ§àﬁ˛[Ô ﬂ€≤˛«ˆ/P˙{ß“Ì∫}_˚k’˝cg˙UF–Ò[2kK\OÉá∂¥‘_PÓı`oà˘N‰ï˚_ˇ“Ûzöw4∏í
>   x©ì©”∫—Œ£üä~¸˜ŸÓk£√¯Ö•áıw¨Â“ÀÈ∆äüÓ≠÷9¨º—c∑=üÿYò˜ä^€

Which appears to be quite an interesting read but I haven't got time to sit down and read it. Now, the file "kind of" downloads, it says it's 748kb in size, and that's the correct size for this photo. However, the file type is unknown to my machine, so I open it in a text editor and it gives the above garbage.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm not echoing anything to the screen before or after this point. I have two include requests at the top, this function and the headers and readfile function.

**FIX UPDATE:**

This was all because the pre-signed AWS S3 link has query string values after the ***proper*** .JPG extension `.JPG?AWSAccessKeyID=345wrdwf`. So when downloaded, it wouldn't recognise the extension. I got round this by creating a unique URL JUST for the header, like so:

```
$headerURL = array_shift(explode('?', basename($url)));
```

Which strips everything before and after the filename. So I ended up with something like this:

```
$url = get_s3_signed_url( $aws_bucketName, 'website-hires-photos/photo/'.$filename, $aws_access_key_id, $aws_s3_secret, 10);
$headerURL = array_shift(explode('?', basename($url)));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$headerURL);
readfile($url);
```

Comment: What type of image is it suppose to be?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid should start with JFIF if JPEG in garbled text...

Comment: Maybe the url isn't generated correctly, did you confirm the url generation is correct, Also you put the whole url as the file attachment name.

Comment: @Musa: The filename is correct as some of the garbage actually makes sense. Every now and then, some of the IPTC/Metadata informations is in pure english, which is being read from the photo's caption, headline and keywords fields. So the photo is being found on S3 but it displays as rubbish.

Comment: @Musa: It has everything to do with Amazon. The content-type on the stored file is image/jpeg, so I cannot see what's wrong with that. I tested this by downloading a photo from another remote server and worked fine.

Comment: @Musa: Take a look at my last update ^^.

Comment: In a previous comment I mentioned about the attachment name, but I didn't think that would cause a problem, try `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($url)."\"");`

Comment: @Musa: Still no joy! This is driving me nuts!

Comment: @Musa: I echoed the URL to screen, copied and pasted it, and then requested that in my browser. It displayed perfectly and expired perfectly.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid how about trying something simple like `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.jpg\"");`

Comment: @Musa: I did this earlier by successfully downloading a photo from another one of my servers. It's just an S3 problem I think.

Comment: You tell us the file should be a photo. Why do you open it using a text editor then? Try opening the file with a picture viewer like [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/). If it displays the picture correctly, then it is only a problem with the filename. Otherwise, something is wrong with the data.

Comment: @Jocelyn: I like your thinking. It wouldn't open in any program but I changed the filename of the download file to photo.jpg and it opened fine in every program. I will post the full amazon URL (expired of course) in an update to see if anybody can see what characters are in the filename that would cause the issue.

Comment: @Jocelyn: I've added the URL in my updated question, maybe/hopefully somebody can spot something.

Comment: @Jocelyn: It's because the S3 signed URL has querystring values after the files extension **.JPG?AWSAccessKeyID=**, please see update 4 & 5 ^^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered my own question but took the knowledge of others to get me to this point, so thank-you.

This was all because the pre-signed AWS S3 URL has query string values after the ***proper*** .JPG extension `/photo.jpg?AWSAccessKeyID=345wrdwf`. So when downloaded, it wouldn't recognise the file extension. I got round this by creating a unique URL **JUST** for the header, like so:

```
$headerURL = array_shift(explode('?', basename($url)));
```

Which strips everything before and after the filename. So I ended up with something like this:

```
$url = get_s3_signed_url( $aws_bucketName, 'website-hires-photos/photo/'.$filename, $aws_access_key_id, $aws_s3_secret, 10);
$headerURL = array_shift(explode('?', basename($url)));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$headerURL);
readfile($url);
```

And saves as a PROPER photo. Wooooo hooooooo!

And this taught me something valuable today. I didn't know that you can add any filename you like in the header attachment field. Whatever you add there is what the file saves as when the user accepts the download. So placing my company name and a download reference was a huuuge bonus.